# Android DatePicker right alignment in TableRow

Tags: android, layout, alignment, android-datepicker

I have added a `DatePicker` to a `TableRow` inside a `TableLayout`. I am trying to perform right alignment of the `DatePicker` (see the code below). However, when I run the application the date picker is not aligned to the right.

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/_row"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/_date"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

How can I align the date picker to the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do something like this:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/_row"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />
    </TableRow>
```

I've changed only the width of the date picker to wrap_content, the date picker is to the right but because is stretched to fill the parent, you can't see that..